# How to find and remove special characters in Excel sheet?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008, ms-office

My Excel sheet contains more than 20000 records in between some where i have values like this à¤¸à¥‹à¤¨à¤¿à¤—à¤°à¤¾ à¤•à¥‡à¤¸à¤° .

How to find these kind of characters ?

I am trying to import this XL Sheet in my Sql server DB but i am getting

"Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this vba?

```
Function RemChrs(s As String) As String
    Static RegEx As Object

    If RegEx Is Nothing Then
        Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        RegEx.Global = True
    End If
    RegEx.Pattern = "à|¤|¸|¥|‹|¨|¿|—|°|¾|•|‡|°"
    RemChrs = RegEx.Replace(s, "")
End Function
```

You can add pattern like |x. Also you can modify code with for loop for run all sheet cell. In this exampe you should use =RemChrs(A1) .

I hope I can help you.

Edit:
If you don't want to use vba, you can edit manually with using ctrl+h and replace all unwanted chars one by one.

Comment: hi thanks for ur answer is there is any way to find it in excel sheet itself?

Answer (score 0):

Ablebits is a good tool to remove any unwanted special characters from excel, specially which comes over during migration. You just need to provide a list of characters to be removed.

Reference : https://www.ablebits.com/excel-clean-cells/howto-remove-chars.php